# Insert Error on Delete

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So I am trying to delete a record from a table and it is getting the strangest error.

The query is

```
DELETE FROM table where column1='x' and column2='y'
```

*note I entered mock names for the table and columns for security reasons.*

Any way I am receiving the error:

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CustomVLANPicsMaintenance, Line 11
Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Which is strange since this is a delete and not an insert.  There are many many stored procedures that are on this server but this specific one "CustomVLANPicsMaintenance" does not exsist anywhere!!!!!!  Its not even related to the table I'm trying to delete rows from.  Whats even more odd is that until recently, the delete method has been working.  I cannot find any links from this table or anything that says it should be running a procedure on delete (although Im not too entirely sure where I would find this).

Has anyone gotten something like this before?

Comment: You do a DELETE and error is about an INSERT. Have you looked inside the triggers?

Comment: The only trigger runs update and select statements.

Answer (score 1):

I'd first try checking if there are any DELETE triggers present on the table. In Management Studio trigger list is located under Databases/%DB name%/Tables/dbo.%Table name%/Triggers.

Comment: OMG THANK THANK THANK YOU!! This trigger wasnt showing up when I was trying to search it by a query!!!!!

Comment: @McSick: If my answer has resolved your question, could you please [Mark it as accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)?